# Fuzzystringmatch gem error

Tags: ruby, rubygems, fuzzy-logic

Im trying to use the `fuzzy-string-match` gem. If I try to load up `irb` and type in `require 'fuzzystringmatch'` I get all these errors

```
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/fuzzy-string-match-0.9.3/lib/fuzzystringmatch/inline/jarowinkler.rb:41:30: error: implicit conversion loses
  integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
_max = s1; _max_length = strlen(s1);
                       ~ ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/fuzzy-string-match-0.9.3/lib/fuzzystringmatch/inline/jarowinkler.rb:42:30: error: implicit conversion loses
  integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
_min = s2; _min_length = strlen(s2);
                       ~ ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/fuzzy-string-match-0.9.3/lib/fuzzystringmatch/inline/jarowinkler.rb:45:30: error: implicit conversion loses
  integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
_max = s2; _max_length = strlen(s2);
                       ~ ^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/fuzzy-string-match-0.9.3/lib/fuzzystringmatch/inline/jarowinkler.rb:46:30: error: implicit conversion loses
  integer precision: 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned long') to 'int' [-Werror,-Wshorten-64-to-32]
_min = s1; _min_length = strlen(s1);
```

Have I done anything wrong? I've not changed the code or anything. How would I fix this? Has anyone come accross this problem?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: It has to be executing 1.9.3 (its showing the path in the errors) because I have 1.8.7 alongside I switch to, but definitely set to 1.9.3

Comment: [I can reproduce this](http://pastebin.com/MLCeqUNA) on OS X 10.7.3 with Ruby 1.9.3p0. It might be worth opening an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/kiyoka/fuzzy-string-match/issues).

Comment: Raised the issue, hopefully they fix it soon

Comment: Any fixes or updates on this issue? I'm running into this on Mountain Lion. Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this issue on my box by sym linking /usr/bin/cc to /usr/bin/gcc. I'm on Mountain Lion and Apple's LLVM was treating those warnings errors.

So, I explicty linked:

`ln -sf /usr/local/Cellar/apple-gcc42/4.2.1-5666.3/bin/gcc-4.2 /usr/bin/cc`